# Guidewire GCC - Show times in local time instead of UTC

Tags: guidewire

The times in GCC, for instance the time of a deployment are all by default on UTC.
Is there anyway to change it so it displays on my local time instead?

The only preference setting I seem to have in GCC is for langage, maybe there is something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamps displayed in the Cloud Console are currently not configurable and are always set to UTC to remove any ambiguity in the ordering of events.

You might consider viewing the logs in DataDog via the "application logs" links shown in the Cloud Console.  The timestamps on log messages are shown in your local time zone (as configured in your DataDog settings) which may be more appropriate to your usage.

Comment: Reading "currently" in your answer makes me wonder : Is it something planned ? 

I understand the choice of a single timezone to prevent ambiguities, but having it configurable would make it more user friendly. 

I am even more confused because some screens in GCC do offer the option to display times in local time (Automated Builds)

Comment: I have no insight into possible future changes so sadly I can't answer your question.  I answered with "currently" because the various components of the Guidewire Cloud infrastructure are being continually improved and I wanted to leave my response open for that reason.  It wouldn't hurt at all to submit this request as an enhancement so that the Guidewire engineering group(s) can add this to their backlog.  Sorry I can't answer your question!